# Don't nil Core Data inverse relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, relationships

I'm modeling a relationship in Core Data where an object Foo can have multiple Item's and an Item cannot exist without a Foo.

In the Core Data model, I have object Foo which has an optional to-many relationship named "items" to object Item where the delete rule is to cascade. Each Item has a non-optional inverse relationship back to Foo named "foo" where the count = 1 and the delete rule is set to nullify.

Currently,

```
foo.items = newItems;
```

results in the inverse relationship to Foo being nil'd for each of the old items. Is there a way to setup Core Data to preserve the inverse relationship on the old items (so they still point back to foo)?

Comment: So, you want `foo.items` to contain all of the old values in `items` plus all of the new ones in `newItems`?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do that? It seems that since you're assigning a new set of Items (who will begin referring to the Foo), the old items should no longer refer to the Foo?